# Typeorm cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression error

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am creating this hige relational database but, for some reason, this particulary Entity is returning me an error when i run its migration and i actually have no ideia why. Could you guys please Help me??

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity('users')
class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    id: number;

    @Column({type: 'varchar', length: 45})
    name: string;

    @Column({type: 'varchar', length: 45, unique: true})
    email: string

    @Column({type: 'boolean', default: false})
    admin: boolean;

    @Column({type: 'varchar', length: 120})
    password: string;

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'timestamp' })
    createdAt: Date | string

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'timestamp', onUpdate: 'timestamp' })
    updatedAt: Date | string

    @Column({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: true })
    deletedAt?: Date | null | undefined | string

}


export { User }
```

i tried adding type 'any' to all parameters but, aparently it didn't work so i'm basically out of options

Comment: What is `default: () => 'timestamp'` supposed to achieve? Did you mean `default: () => new Date()` or `default: 'now'`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function or now() should work also - have not tried now()... below works in my codebase.

```
@Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
```